# pyTorch: how to reset its state?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, pytorch, torch

I'm using pyTorch and for some reason - after refactoring my code - it's not working anymore. The error is:

```
  File ".\api\deepmatcher\data\dataset.py", line 420, in load_cache
    cached_data = torch.load(cachefile)
  File "c:\...\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 592, in load
    return _load(opened_zipfile, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "c:\...\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 851, in _load
    result = unpickler.load()
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deepmatcher'
```

After some research I've learned that pyTorch is saving its state somehow (`state_dict`?), classes it uses and so on.

How can I reset pyTorch to its plain state, so I can run my code again? Maybe deleting some files on my computer (it's Win10 btw)? Or running some magical python command?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove all `cacheddata.pth` files from the project.